# Error trying to unlist a dataframe from a list of dataframes and vectors

Tags: r

I have a list named `b.list` containing vector and dataframes inside. The 1st entry contains a dataframe (2 or more cols), for which I want to compute covariance using cov function but it requires a matrix as argument.

So I've tried this by two ways:

1. `as.matrix(unlist (b.list[1]))` but gives me a char vector
2. `as.matrix(b.list[1])` but since the argument is a list cannot coerce properly.

The dataframe is a product of `cbind` operation.

How can I "unlist" a cbind matrix without turning it into a vector, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not even need to use `unlist` here.  Just access the first element and then convert to a matrix:

```
as.matrix(b.list[[1]])
```

Note that to access the actual element inside the first position in the list, we use `[[1]]` double brackets, not single brackets.  `b.list[1]` is actually a *list*, with one element inside it.